# Making WinRAR extract archives by default when double clicking RAR files?

Tags: windows-7, winrar

With WinRAR installed, when you right-click on a .rar file in Windows, you can browse to `WinRAR -> Extract to [archive name]` in the context menu, and WinRAR will extract the archive to a folder in the current directory.

Is there a way of making WinRAR do this by default, simply by double-clicking on the archive?

I rarely use WinRAR to actually browse archives and instead always use this context menu option so it would save considerable time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open `regedit`
2. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WinRAR\shell\open\command`
3. Change the **(Default)** value from `"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" "%1"`
   to `"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x "%1"`
4. If you have ZIP files associated with WinRAR too, change the corresponding value under
   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WinRAR.ZIP\shell\open\command` too.

(Obviously for 32-bit WinRAR the path will be different.)

This however will probably not create a sub-directory named after the archive in the current directory while extracting. (At least it doesn't for me given my WinRAR settings.) For that you'll have to change the **(Default)** value(s) mentioned above to something like `"C:\Extract.bat" "%1"`, then create the batch file with the following content (just a single line):

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x %1 "%~n1\"
```

This should do what you want, and as a bonus you can now right-click and "Open" multiple archives (or select them and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and they will all be automatically extracted to individual sub-directories by the batch file.

If you would also like to open a new window for the folder(s) the files were extracted to once the extraction process is complete, instead of the line above, use the following line in the batch file (again, just a single line):

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x %1 "%~n1\" && C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "start "" "%~n1\""
```

Note: The `Extract to <archive name\>` context menu entry is generated dynamically by the shell extension based on the archive's name, so no key by that name exists in the registry. For a static key it would be simple to just set it as the default action instead of Open, but this is not possible here due to the dynamic nature of the option.

Comment: Thanks, worked good for me, it just extracts to the same folder which is fine for me.  Using win 8 64 bit.

Comment: @Codezilla: Yes, it'll extract to the same folder as I mentioned above unless you create the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I try what Karan say but it create a weird folder name like "%~n1". That should remove to the file path (%1) the extension .zip or .rar (%~n1) but don't work -.-

To do a folder with the same name as the file you have to change the register **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WinRAR\shell\open\command** (change HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\**WinZIP**\shell\open\command too) to

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"  x %1 "%1_\"
```

That will create a folder like C:\Path\< namefolder >.zip_

It's not perfect but it is.

I love you Karan.